# How do I get the kicker member to be transferrable amongst the three gas stations below?

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, polymorphism, instance

Given the Kickback class, and the three subclasses that are subclasses of Store which is a subclass of Kickback. With the understanding that the Kicker member in this class holds the Kickback points which are encapsulated to be returned to be returned to the dummy in the Person class. How do I get the kicker member in the Kickback subclass to be transferable amongst the three gas stations. So in other words, how do I set the kicker in Kickback and the encapsulated member points in Person to hold 85 points after a variation of Divine visits and 210 points after earning 125 points at a 76 visit? The following code is the Kickback class, the Person object, and the gas stations described above. Any honest help is appreciated. If it still may be a big code- dump, I apologize; I am trying to be as straightforward as I can.

Kickback

```
import java.util.*;

public class Kickback{

    public static final int START = 0;
    public static final int REWARD = 50;

    protected Person visitor;
    protected int purchase, kicker;
    protected String name;

    public Kickback(){
    visitor = new Person(purchase,kicker);
    name = "Darin Douglas";
    }

    public double get_points(){
      return kicker += purchase/REWARD;
    }

    public boolean redeem_points(){
    if(kicker < purchase){
         purchase -= kicker;
         zeroKB();
         return true;
    }
    kicker -= purchase;
    return false;
    }
    public double zeroKB(){
    return kicker = START;
    }
}
```

Divine

```
public class Divine extends Store{
    protected int puncher, drinks;
    protected String freebie;
    public static final double COST = 99;
    public static final int COFFEES = 5;
    public static final String FREEBIE = "Congratulations, you have earned a free coffee!";
    public Divine(){
    super();
    puncher = COFFEES;
    freebie = FREEBIE;
    }
    public void init(){
    drink();
    purchase += drinks*COST;
    System.out.println("Just note:\n You have " +drinks+ " and your purchase so far is "+purchase);
    super.init();
    System.out.println(toString());
    }
     public void drink(){
    System.out.print("How many coffees?\n99 cents each\n");
    drinks = scan.nextInt();
    if(puncher == super.START)
        free_coffee();
    puncher -= drinks;
    }
    private void free_coffee(){
    System.out.println(freebie);
        reset();
    }
    public String toString(){
      return name + ",\nYou have " + kicker + " points.\nAnd have " +puncher+ " coffees remaining.";
    }
    public int reset(){
       return puncher = COFFEES;
    }
}
```

SeventySix:

```
import java.util.*;
public class SeventySix extends Store{
    public SeventySix(){
    super();
    }
    public void nav(){
    super.init();
    System.out.print(super.toString());
    }
}
```

Jmart:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Jmart extends Store{
    public static final int PERCENT = 100;
    public Jmart(){
    super();
    }
    public void init(){
    System.out.print("Enter in an amount: ");
    purchase = scan.nextInt();
        get_points();
    super.spend_money();
    System.out.println(super.toString());
    }
    public double get_points(){
        return kicker += purchase/PERCENT;
    }
}
```

The dummy:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Person{
    private int cash, debit, amount, points;  
    public static final int CASH = 1000;
    public static final int CREDIT = 3000;

  public Person(int purchase, int kicker){
    cash = CASH;
    debit = CREDIT;
    amount = purchase;
    points = kicker;
    }
    public boolean use_cash(){
    if(cash < amount){
        amount -=  cash;
        System.out.println("We got " + cash + "cash.\nYour remaining balance is " + amount + "\nPlease try another method of payment.");
        reset_cash();
        return true;
}
        cash -= amount;
    return false;
    }
    public boolean use_card(){
    if(debit < amount){
        System.out.println("Card Declined.\nPlease try another method of payment.");
        return true;
    }
        debit -= amount;
    return false;
    }
    public double reset_cash(){
    return cash = Kickback.START;
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the naming conventions. It makes everything much less painful for all of us.

Comment: And formatting too. Code dumps are difficult.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TL;DR

Comment: I did shorten this down a lot. How is it still too long?

Answer (score 1):

So since you've posted your entire code and the code is quite long and will take a while for just one person to decipher and debug, I will get you started. First of all, I understand that the purpose of Kickback class you've created is to model the Kickback card to store rewards points. Thus, by creating a class you've created a user-defined type. In your method "get_points" you pass "Double Kickback" as a parameter. Parameters and variables are represented by a type and an identifier which corresponds to a value. The parameter would be "Kickback myCard" or something of that sort but in this case, since you are trying to modify the value of a Kickback card, and you are within the Kickback class, you do not need a parameter of type Kickback. You just need to modify a private member of the class called cardValue that perhaps has the type double, directly.  Java does not support operator overloading. You cannot just do Kickback++. So when you declare the private members, declare an attribute called myCardValue:

```
    double myCardValue;
```

Thus, instead of doing

```
    Kickback += purchase*REWARD;
```

you would need to modify the myCardValue member:

```
    myCardValue += purchase*REWARD.
```

NOTE: Scanner SHOULD NOT be a member of Kickback and neither should those constants. Those constants should just be declared and initialized outside of the classes in your program. They're public so they will be accessible by all classes.

Given that you want to use this member in other classes, you must supply getter and setter methods (a.k.a accessor and mutator methods) that interact with the myCardValue member of Kickback class. Ex.

```
    public static double getKickBackCardVal(){
        return myCardValue;
    }
```

Just remember, Kickback is a type/object. In your Person class, Person should have an attribute that is a declaration of an instance of the Kickback class:

```
    Kickback myCard;
```

because I'm assuming in your world, you want the dummy to have a Kickback card. Hopefully this helped. I apologize for such a long and convoluted explanation but you've posted your entire code to debug and judging from your code, you've shown that you need somewhat of better a understanding of classes and objects, how they are created and interacted with.

Comment: Thank you very much for the starter yesterday. I managed to create a Kickback Object that will point to all the members of the Kickback class. I have a feeling the Kickback class is now doing its job. Now, it is a matter of revising it so I do not have to pass the cash, debit and credit members in to Store. And still, setting it up so the Store methods work in all the gas stations and override where appropriate. I revised the code from yesterday above with your help.